# Converting multiple unique strings to single string with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset about Avocados I am working with. The data spans 3 years with each row representing a new week. In which case, every date is a unique string value. Is it possible for me to change these strings into a single string value? For example, for all string values that contain "2015" I would like to get rid of the month and day, and have one value of "2015" so I can assess the data on a yearly basis.

I have tried the following: (df.loc[df['Date']=='2015'])

However, this returns no results as pandas is searching for only the string '2015', is there a way to set this up so that it pulls all the data the contains '2015' in the string value?

In which case, for all the strings that contain '2015' I would like to change them into one new value '2015' with the month and day removed.

Thanks for your help in advance!

```
    Region  Date         AvgPrice
0   Albany  2015-12-27       1.33
1   Albany  2015-12-20       1.35
2   Albany  2015-12-13       0.93
3   Albany  2015-12-06       1.08
4   Albany  2015-11-29       1.28
```

Comment: Date is a str or datetime column?

Comment: Date is a string, thanks so much for your edit too!

Comment: Convert to a `datetime64[ns]` dtype then you have all of this information available thorugh the `.dt` (datetime) accessor. Worth a read: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [`pandas.Series.dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date).dt.strftime("%Y")
```

Basically, you have to convert the column to datetime in order to extract the year.

---

Another approach is to use [`pandas.Series.str.slice`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.slice.html):

```
df["Date"] = df.Date.str.slice(0,4)
```

Comment: Bro you're a wizard thank you so much, my life just got 1000x better.

Comment: @LeeHarveyOswald nice to help you! please consider mark it as accepted

Comment: One more question. When I try and set the new column 'Date' equal to these new values. 

With:        df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date).dt.strftime("%Y").apply

I end up with the date column full of NaNs. Sorry for being such a noobie.

Comment: what function are you applying? I mean `apply` is a method which receives a function (e.g. `df.apply(sum)`)

Comment: Woop nevermind, instead of changing the Date column I just made a new column 'NewDates' with the new values. Thanks again for your help! I really appreciate it! :)

Comment: @LeeHarveyOswald great! I added a new (probably better) approach

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with [`Series.dt.year`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.year.html) here.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.year
```

**Note**: `Series.dt.year` returns `int64` dtype, while `Series.dt.strftime` returns dtype str.

Comment: Pandas is awesome, thank you so much for your help. People on this website give me hope for humanity.